# Android Raw Array

Tags: android

I have an array of sound

```
int mySounds ={R.raw.sound1,R.raw.sound2,R.raw.sound3}
```

Am later creating a sound by

```
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,mySounds[0] );
    mp.start();
```

Was wondering if there is anyway to just use strings in the array

```
String mySounds ={"sound1.mp3","sound2.mp3"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You have to look up the resource by using getIdentifier

```
String mySounds ={"sound1","sound2"};
int mp3Resource = getResources().getIdentifier(mySounds[0], "raw" , String packageName);
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,mp3Resource );
mp.start();
```

Resource names are without extension. So it's not sound1.mp3, but sound1.

Comment: That's reflection. Is there a way without it?